# How to remove pieces of data from string

Tags: c#, string

I have a text file with multiple entries of this format:

```
Page: 1 of 1
Report Date: January 15 2018
Mr. Gerald M. Abridge ID #: 0000008 1 Route 81 Mr. Gerald Michael Abridge Pittaburgh PA 15668 SSN: XXX-XX-XXXX
Birthdate: 01/00/1998 Sex: M
COURSE Course Title CRD GRD GRDPT COURSE Course Title CRD GRD GRDPT
FALL 2017 (08/28/2017 to 12/14/2017) CS102F FUND. OF IT & COMPUTING 4.00 A 16.00 CS110 C++ PROGRAMMING I 3.00 A- 11.10 EL102 LANGUAGE AND RHETORIC 3.00 B+ 9.90 MA109 CALC WITH APPLICATIONS I 4.00 A 16.00 SP203 INTERMEDIATE SPANISH I 3.00 A 12.00
EHRS QHRS QPTS GPA Term 17.00 17.00 65.00 3.824 Cum 17.00 17.00 65.00 3.824
Current Program(s): Bachelor of Science in Computer Science
End of official record.
```

---

So far, I have read the text file into a string, `full`. I want to be able to remove first two lines of each of the entries. How would I go about doing this?

Here's the code that I used to read it in:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default))
{
    string full = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? Or are you simply trying to get someone to do the work for you?

Comment: Hint: `StreamReader` has a `ReadLine` method too...

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet I've attempted using `.split` to split each one into different string arrays and then using `.remove` to remove a certain number of characters but when I use `.split`, since it splits it into an array, the lines are then gone and the number of characters to remove varies

Comment: Do the lines you want to remove *always* start with `Page:` and `Report Date:`? Can you just skip lines that begin with that text?

Comment: @RufusL yes they do, how would I skip the lines that begin with that text?

Comment: What's your expected output? Please update the question.

Comment: Can you post more than one entry so I can see the how each block starts. Is each entry on it own page?  With very large files reading the entire input into memory may not be the best solution.  It may be better to read one line at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the lines you want to skip begin with the same strings, you can put those prefixes in a list and then, when you're reading the lines, skip the any that being with one of the prefixes:

This will leave you with a list of strings that represent all the file lines that don't begin with one of the specified prefixes:

```
var filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";
var ignorePrefixes = new List<string> {"Page:", "Report Date:"};

var filteredContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Where(line => ignorePrefixes.All(prefix => !line.StartsWith(prefix)))
    .ToList();
```

If you want all the content as a single string, you can use `String.Join`:

```
var filteredAsString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filteredContent);
```

If Linq isn't your thing, or you don't understand what it's doing, here's the "old school" way of doing the same thing:

```
List<string> filtered = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    bool okToAdd = true;

    foreach (string prefix in ignorePrefixes)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(prefix))
        {
            okToAdd = false;
            break;         
        }
    }

    if (okToAdd)
    {
        filtered.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked great, thanks! I'm going to look more into linq, it seems pretty neat

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadReportFile(FileInfo file)
{
     var line = String.Empty;
     var page = "Page:";
     var date = "Report Date:";
     using(var reader = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
          while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
               while(line.IndexOf(page) == -1 AND line.IndexOf(date) == -1)
                    yield return line;
}
```

Code is pretty straight forward, while line is not null and doesn't contain page or date, return line.  You could condense or even get fancier, building lookups for your prefix etc. but if the code is simple or not needed to be that complex, this should suffice.